# A while loop with Try Catch throws exceptions after loop ends

Tags: c#, selenium, loops, try-catch, nunit

I am working on writing some web-tests using Nunit with selenium in C#
I have made a method which results in some weird behavior.

The point of the method is to try some action.

If the action succeeds exit the method.

If the action throws an exception, wait 100 ms and try it again.

If the action has been tried more than some timeout integer, throw an timeout exception.

I also wanted to add an option to do some other action if action throws an exception.

This is the code:

```
    public void Tryfor(Action tryAct, Action catchAct = null, int timeout = 50)
    {
        while (true) //loops until error or exception
        {
            Console.WriteLine(timeout); //For debugging
            if (timeout-- < 0) throw new TimeoutException("Tryfor timed out"); //reduce timeout by 1, when it reaches 0 throw exception
            try
            {
                tryAct();
                break; // If the try action succeeds with no exception, exit loop
            }
            catch   //If any exception is throw in the try action 
            {
                catchAct?.Invoke(); //If an action has been passed in the catch action, evoke it, else do nothing
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100); //wait 100 ms and try the try action again
        }
    }
```

This works just fine mos of the time, but as mentioned it sometimes behaves in a weird way i cant really understand.

What often happens is that the method runs through, maybe fails 2 times before it succeeds. Then after succeeding, it throws all the errors it caught.

What happens more often is that it reaches the timeout, meaning it failed (in this case) 50 times.
Then instead of just throwing the timeout error, it throws the 50 errors it should have caught.

My goal is of course just to make a method which does what i described, but i would really like to understand how and why it throws all those errors it caught.

Comment: Do the cases you described always happen when called with the same parameters? Also how do you know that "*it throws the 50 errors it should have caught*", as the first thrown error should have stopped the program if not caught properly?

Comment: @Rafalon No, i use it for a couple of diffrent tests.
I for example have one where i can see from the log that it tried 13 times before it passed, then it continued with the test, and once the test had finished, it threw those 13 exceptions. Resulting in a test that succeded reporting as fail.

Comment: I've created a .NET Fiddle with your code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7YuI7V) but it doesn't appear to have the same issues. We'll need more information about what the parameters are

Comment: The one that failed 13 times was just this action passed to the method:             Assert.AreEqual(Activecheckbox.Selected, true);
Nothing else.
Just failed a couple of times until the checkbox had loaded in properly

Comment: Is your `catchAct` always the same? And if so, can you provide its definition?

Comment: In this and most cases its just null, so nothing happens. The few times i have something in there is for returning to the default frame if the action passed had to go into a iframe

Comment: When you say "*13 exceptions are being thrown*", do you mean that you see "*50 49 48 47 ... 37*" in your console, or do you **really** mean *13 exceptions are **thrown***? If the latter, can you show us the exact 13 exceptions message errors?

Comment: This is in the output:
 Multiple failures or warnings in test:
      1)   Expected: False
      But was:  True
    
      2)   Expected: False
      But was:  True
    
      3)   Expected: False
      But was:  True
  And so on up till 13 or 50 or however many times it failed.

If i just saw the number in the output that would be within expected behavior, but this doesnt really make any sense to me

Comment: Oh wait, you mean you are passing `Assert`s as `tryAct` methods? So it's like you were writing `for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) { Assert.AreEqual(...,...); Thread.Sleep(100); }` just with a bit of try/catching or so. Be aware that in a test method, if any of the `Assert`s fails, the whole test fails. It's normal behaviour, and also it is different from thrown exceptions. I think you should include your test methods in your question, as it will clarify it a lot

Comment: That explains it actually, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment you made, I see that some of your actions include Asserts, such as `Assert.AreEqual`.

When an assertion fails, NUnit does two things:

1. It records the failure.
2. It terminates execution of the test by throwing an exception.

If you catch the exception, you prevent the second step... the test does not terminate. But the first step has already taken place... the failure has already been reported.

The solution in your case is to move all your assertions outside of the actions, into the test body itself. For example, you could assert that no exception was thrown. In the actions, throw some other kind of exception... a simple `System.Exception` will do. For example, in place of `Assert.AreEqual(a, b)`, use

```
if (a != b)
    throw new Exception("A was not equal to B");
```

Just don't throw, explicitly or via Assert, any NUnit exceptions.